# SQL Agent 2012 fails with error code : 0x00000001 however SQL Agent 2008 successfully executes for the same package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have tried to execute a package containing script component which uses Excel Component in SQL Agent 2012 but has failed with

```
Code: 0x00000001 Source: Backlog Supplies Validation Description: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
End Error DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)
```

However when I call the same package via SQL Agent 2008 R2 initially it failed with  error code : 0x00000001 . Later it succeeded after creating a folder with name  "Desktop" in the following path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile" .

However doing the same in SQL Agent 2012 server is not working out .

Please note SQL Agent 2012 is in a different server having Windows server 2012 
SQL Agent 2008 R2 is in a server that has Windows server 2008 installed.

At both servers , package has been successfully migrated and executed

Comment: There must be more error messages than '0x00000001'. Please post them.

Comment: Hi Please find the description :    Code: 0x00000001     Source: Backlog Supplies Validation      Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

Comment: Is this you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f682f047-153c-4ced-81f0-0b2c8d68f1ad/ssis-script-excel-automation-and-sql-agent-problem?forum=sqlintegrationservices ?

Comment: Here's another: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64?forum=innovateonoffice. If you want ti investigate the problem further you could use processmon to identify if the process is failing to create a required file.

Comment: Thanks for the help however, my packages are on Windows Server 2012 and we are seeing this issue

Comment: It could still be the same issue. The second one doesn't even mention a windows version.