# SSIS Script task failed when I run SSIS package through T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I wrote a SSIS script task where I use C# code to read data from a database using ODBC and then dynamically create an excel spreadsheet using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel object. The code then saves the spreadsheet to a directory folder .

When I execute the package in the SQL Server Business Development Studio, it works perfectly and the package writes the spreadsheet to the folder without any problem, but when I run through T_SQL code it fails script task.See the following Script task code:-

It works fine when I execute directly from BI tool,
but fails when I execute through T_SQL Code-

```
    @Cmd VARCHAR(4000),
    @ReturnCode INT,
    @Msg VARCHAR(1000)

    SELECT @Cmd = 'DTEXEC /FILE "' + @Path + 'Package.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT 1 /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW'

    EXEC @ReturnCode = xp_cmdshell @Cmd
```

Error:-

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>       Version 12.0.5000.0 for 64-bit
>       Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>       NULL
>       Started:  12:05:47 PM
>       Error: 2016-09-08 12:05:49.42
>          Code: 0x00000001
>          Source: Script Task 
>          Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>       End Error
>       Warning: 2016-09-08 12:05:49.42
>          Code: 0x80019002
>          Source: Package 
>          Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1)
>   reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs
>   when the number of errors reaches the number specifie
>       d in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>       End Warning
>       DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>       Started:  12:05:47 PM
>       Finished: 12:05:49 PM
>       Elapsed:  1.828 seconds
>       NULL

Comment: Permissions issue? Also, It's really a bad practice to even enable xp_cmdshell , use SQL Server Agent to launch dts packages.

Comment: I have given the valid permissions but not working

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531706/sql-agent-2012-fails-with-error-code-0x00000001-however-sql-agent-2008-success), where @Nick.McDermaid references other [similar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f682f047-153c-4ced-81f0-0b2c8d68f1ad/ssis-script-excel-automation-and-sql-agent-problem?forum=sqlintegrationservices) questions.

They all point to the answer [outlined here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64?forum=innovateonoffice)

> A Desktop folder seems to be necessary in the systemprofile folder to open >file by Excel.
>
> This solution is ...
>
> ・Windows 2008 Server x64
>
> Please make this folder.
>
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
>
> ・Windows 2008 Server x86
>
> Please make this folder.
>
> C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
>
> This operation took away office automation problems in my system.